# Not able to change color on checked/uncheck item on gridview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

i have written following code:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (position == 0) {

            gridview.setItemChecked(1, false);
            gridview.setItemChecked(2, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.indian_size);

            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9AD082"));

            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
        if (position == 1 || position == 2 ) {

            gridview.setItemChecked(0, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.indian_size);

            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9AD082"));


            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);


        }

    }
});
```

When i click the item at `0` position  then it change the color and it also work for the position for `1` and `2` .

But now i want like when i click on position `1` and `2` then i need to clear the text color and background color of position `0` and vice versa.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Determine if you already checked the item by calling `getCheckedItemPositions()`:

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = gridView.getCheckedItemPositions();
if (checkedPositions != null && checkedPositions.get(position)) {
  // Position is already checked, un-check it
} else {
  // Position is un-checked, check it
}
```

Comment: If i have selected the item at position `0` and if i select the item at position `1` then i need to cleat the color of item at position `0` or set to default on `gridview setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: where i have write this code? With thing the if else statement?